# How to specify multiple OU in DN in ldif file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, ldap, spring-ldap

I have an ldif file which I am running on a local server. Below is the code from my ldif file which has issues. Code1 works fine but Code2 doesn't work and gives the below error, what do I need to do to accomplish multiple OU's in the DN of my ldif file? To clarify further, I am implementing LDAP with Spring boot and am using this ldif file for testing purposes.

```
Caused by: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException: Unable to add entry 'CN=lastname\, firstname,OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com' because its parent entry 'OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com' does not exist in the server.
```

I've looked extensively on the web and couldn't find a solution. I've been scratching my head for 2 days!!

```
# Code1
dn: dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: example

# Organizational Units
dn: ou=Unit1,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Unit1

dn: ou=Unit2,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Unit2

# Create People
dn: CN=lastname\, firstname,OU=Unit1,DC=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: firstname, lastname
sn: lastname

# Code2
dn: dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: example

# Organizational Units
dn: ou=Unit1,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Unit1

dn: ou=Unit2,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Unit2

# Create People
dn: CN=lastname\, firstname,OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: firstname, lastname
sn: lastname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have twice the same entry definition in your ldif (#code 1 and #code 2 look the same).

```
parent entry 'OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com' does not exist
```

-> Yes there is no entry with `dn: OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com`

If you need a "Unit1" as sub entry of "Unit2", delete the duplicate entry `dn:OU=Unit1,DC=com` and add this one after "Unit2" instead :

```
dn: OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Unit1
```

Once created, this entry - as a "parent" - should allow creating the "child" user entry `dn: CN=lastname\, firstname,OU=Unit1,OU=Unit2,DC=com`

See [LDAP DNs and RDNs](https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/)